# Why am I getting "Null check operator used on a null value" from using rootBundle.load during a Flutter test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I searched for quite a while and didn't find a clear solution to this issue on SO or other sites.

I have a Flutter test:

```
test('Create Repo and Read JSON', () {
  Repository repository = CreateRepository();
  ...
}
```

`CreateRepository()` eventually calls a method with the following code:

```
var jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString(vendorDataFilePath);
```

This results in the error: `Null check operator used on a null value`

None of my executed code was using a null check operator (`!`) so where is this error coming from and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After running the test in Debug mode, I found the error is actually in `asset_bundle.dart` within Flutter itself, not from my code.

```
final ByteData? asset =
    await ServicesBinding.instance!.defaultBinaryMessenger.send('flutter/assets', encoded.buffer.asByteData());
```

It's the `instance!` that causes the error because `instance` is actually null at this point, so the null check operator (`!`) fails.

Unfortunately, rather than a nice descriptive error message like we normally get from Flutter, this results in a more cryptic error description directly from Dart.  The root cause in my case was that an extra call is required in the test to make sure `instance` gets initialized.

```
test('Create Repo and Read JSON', () {
  // Add the following line to the top of the test
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // <--
  Repository repository = CreateRepository();
  ...
}
```